# Чем является каретка для JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Почитав статьи о создании собственных WYSIWYG-редакторов для админ-панелей,
я предположил, что для JavaScript просто-напросто не существует никакой каретки
внутри полей ввода, потому он не может с ней работать и решение таких элементарных на первый взгляд задачи, как окружение каретки чем-либо, перемещение каретки на нужную позицию, регистрация текущей позиции каретки и т. д. достигается рулонами нечитаемого кода. Верно ли, что JavaScript не видит каретки в браузере?

---

**Обновление** (перенесено из комментария)

Информация из всех образовавшихся в комментариях обсуждений, безусловно, пригодится, но я вернусь к основной теме. Спрошу так: вот есть курсор внутри поля ввода и есть JavaScript. Какова причина, по которой в нативном JavaScript отсутствует средства для работы с кареткой типа `getCaretPosition()`, `moveCaretToPosition()`, `getTextAfterCaret()` и т. д.? Наверняка это не лень разработчиков, а какие-то трудности взаимодействия JavaScript с браузером.

Comment: А что для вас "каретка в браузере"? Имеете в виду каретку в полях ввода DOM? Можно пойти дальше, `javascript не видит никакого браузера`

Comment: Каретка - это на печатной машинке. Есть местоположение курсора. И оно является свойством конкретного контрола (скажем, текстбокса), и соответственно для каждого контрола своё значение.

Comment: @Akina, Просто слово "курсор" употребляют как по отношению к указателю мыши, так и к указателю внутри поля. Но с терминологией ладно. Вы бы не могли привести пример, как обратиться к соответствующим свойствам у textarea?

Comment: @vp_arth, так точно, каретка внутри полей ввода DOM.

Comment: [Caret position in textarea, in characters from the start](http://stackoverflow.com/q/263743/2881286)

Comment: какую позицию ты хочешь? в символах? в пикселях?

Comment: @Grundy пиксели нам незачем: как и в небраузерных тектовых редакторах, интерес представляет собой позиция строка-колонка

Comment: Ладно, информация из всех образовавшихся обсуждений, безусловно, пригодится, но я вернусь к основной теме. Спрошу так: вот есть курсор внутри поля ввода и есть JavaScript. Какова причина, по которой в нативном `JavaScript` отсутствует средства для работы с кареткой типа `getCaretPosition()`, `moveCaretToPosition()`, `getTextAfterCaret()` и т. д.? Наверняка это не лень разработчиков, а какие-то трудности взаимодействия JavaScript и курсора.

Comment: @GurebuBokofu, _Какова причина, по которой в нативном JavaScript отсутствует средства для работы с кареткой_ - это не нужно. Вообще говоря, тут скорее вопрос к DOM, а не к JavaScript.

Comment: Похоже что вы путаете JavaScript и [DOM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model), последний как раз и имеет дело со всем чего вы ждете от JavaScript. JavaScript же сам по себе просто язык, он не имеет никакого представления о браузере и тем более о каретке. Более того, он и **_не должен знать_** о таких вещах, т.к. [область применения JavaScript](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#.D0.9E.D0.B1.D0.BB.D0.B0.D1.81.D1.82.D1.8C_.D0.BF.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D1.8F) не ограничена одними только браузерами.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Объект [`Selection`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Selection) представляет диапазон текста выделенный пользователем или текущую позицию курсора (каретки).

Этот объект не является частью JavaScript, он реализуется браузером.

Для управления курсором в [`TextArea`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLTextAreaElement) есть следующие поля:

- `selectionStart` Возвращает/задаёт индекс начала выделенного текста. Если нет выделенного текста, возвращает индекс символа следующего за курсором.
- `selectionEnd` Возвращает/задаёт индекс окончания выделенного текста. Если нет выделенного текста, возвращает индекс символа следующего за курсором.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ! Подскажите пожалуйста, что значит "не является частью JavaScript, а реализуется браузером"? Если этот объект есть, значит он должен быть где-то представлен на каком-либо языке, а если не на JavaScript, то на каком?

Comment: JavaScript - язык, описываемый набором стандартов ECMA, каждый браузер имеет собственную реализацию языка и среды исполнения. Selection - часть среды исполнения в браузере. Например его нет в реализации JavaScript в node.js или старых версиях популярных браузеров.